# Apex Oracle Javascript validation

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to Incorporate a `javascript validation` on an `application in apex`. 
Basically, what should happen is that the validation should run if i click on a `textfield` or another `Item type`. I want to the validation to runs `without` me having to click on a submit or save button.

*For an example if I was filling out a form, I want to validation straight after the user click from `"FirstName"` field to `"LastName"` and each individual field will have it own validation*.

The reason why I want to do this is because I have an application which takes about 15-30 minutes to fill out and sometimes after you spend all those mins filling it out and click on save or create. you get a long list of validation errors. To avoid this I want to use javascript/Ajax to do a validation which validate individual fields straight after you click from one field to another.

I have a feeling it can be done but i dont know how. Please point me on the right direction.

**EDITED**

for an example I have this `validations`

```
begin
  if length(:p1_subject) >3 then 
    return false;
  else 
    return true;
  end if;
end;
```

This validation will only run when i click on the `create button` but I want it to work everything you click off and on the `p1_subject` field.

Hope I am making sense.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What version of APEX do you have? If you have at least 4.0, I'll explain how to use dynamic actions to solve your problem.

Comment: I was writing out a long solution, and I found an [a open source plugin](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=59381) which does exactly what you want.

Comment: @RohanM you can still post your long solution as the answer as well. Thanks very much

Comment: I came across a few complications when writing my solution. I was basically writing everything including CSS, whereas the plugin takes care of that you. If you still can't get it working, I'll have another go.

Comment: @RohanM I looked at the explain and I wanted it to come up as a alert when a field doesnt meet the validation

Comment: @RohanM or maybe a javascript that calls a procedure might be a good way because javascript still runs after a page as been loaded... That plugin wouldnt work for me because thats for finding it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165073/including-alert-message-for-my-dynamic-actions for a possible solution.