# Including alert message for my dynamic Actions

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a set of text Field items in oracle apex:

- Order Number
- Revision Number

When we open the report, revision should be hidden.

Only when the user enters unique order number (non-duplicate order numbers), revision number should be visible.

If he enters duplicate order number, revision number should be hidden.

I have created these dynamic actions and it is working fine.

If the order number is duplicate I need to put a alert saying "This is a Duplicate value"? Where do I include the alert message in the dynamic actions I have created below?

Incidentally, my dynamic actions are working fine. I just need to accommodate the alert message for the following dynamic action:

Step 1. Create three Page Items

1. P1_ORDER_NO - Text Field
2. P1_REVISION_NO - Text Field
3. P1_ENABLE_DISABLE_REVNO  - Hidden,Value Protected - No

Step 2. Create 3 Dynamic Actions

1) Disable revision number on page load

```
Event - Page Load
Action - Disable
Fire When Event Result Is  - True
Selection Type - Item
Item - P1_REVISION_NO
```

2) Check duplicate order number

```
Event - Change
Selection Type - Item(s)
Item(s) - P1_ORDER_NO
Condition - is not null

Action - Execute PL/SQL Code
Generate opposite false action - Unchecked
Fire When Event Result Is  - True
Fire on page load - Unchecked
Stop Execution On Error - Checked
Wait for Result - Checked
PL/SQL Code -
declare  
l_count number;  
begin  
select count(*) into l_count  
from emp  
where empno = :P1_ORDER_NO;  

if l_count > 0 then  
:P1_ENABLE_DISABLE_REVNO := 1;  
else  
:P1_ENABLE_DISABLE_REVNO := 0;  
end if;  
end;  

Page Items to Submit = P1_ORDER_NO
Page Items to Return  = P1_ENABLE_DISABLE_REVNO
```

3) Enable and Disable Revision Number

```
Event - Change
Selection Type - Item(s)
Item(s) - P1_ENABLE_DISABLE_REVNO
condition - greater than or equal to
value  - 1

Action - Disable
Fire on Page Load - Unchecked
Generate opposite false action - checked
Selection Type = Item(s)
Item(s) - P1_REVISION_NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second action to the 3rd event:

- Type = Alert
- Text = This is a duplicate value